# ANT build runs fine with WS_ANT but fails in RAD

Tags: ant, websphere, websphere-7, ibm-rational

Just trying to run ANT script with in IBM RAD\RSA 8 to deploy to websphere .
It works fine when run from command prompt using WS_ANT.bat but inside RAD fails with following error

```
Unable to determine WAS Home directory. Please use the wasHome task attribute or set the was.root System property.
```

Following is basic ANT script copied from SO and Modified again runs fine from WS_ANT but not from RAD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<projectname="project"default="wasListApps"basedir=".">
        <description>
        Script for listing installed apps.
        Example run from:
        /opt/IBM/SDP70/runtimes/base_v61/profiles/AppSrv01/bin
    </description>

        <propertyname="was_home"location="C:\Program Files\ibm\SDP80\runtimes\base_v7"/>       

        <pathid="was.runtime">
                <filesetdir="${was_home}/lib">
                        <includename="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
                <filesetdir="${was_home}/plugins">
                        <includename="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
        </path>
        <propertyname="was_cp"value="${toString:was.runtime}">
        </property>
        <propertyname="was_server"value="server1"/>
        <propertyenvironment="env">
        </property>

        <targetname="wsStopServer">
                <taskdefname="wsStopServer"classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.StopServer"classpath="${was_cp}">
                </taskdef>
                <wsStopServerserver="${was_server}"failonerror="false"/>
        </target>

        <targetname="wsStartServer" depends="wsStopServer">
                        <taskdefname="wsStartServer"classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.StartServer"classpath="${was_cp}">
                        </taskdef>
                        <wsStartServerserver="${was_server}"failonerror="true"/>
                </target>


        <targetname="wasListApps"depends="wsStartServer">
                <taskdefname="wsListApp"classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.ListApplications"classpath="${was_cp}">
                </taskdef>
                <wsListAppwasHome="${was_home}"/>
        </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the **ws_ant.bat** file you will find it calls the **setupCmdLine.bat** first thing to, you guessed it, setup the command line. That file tries to determine the **WAS_HOME** environment variable by setting it to the parent directory.

```
SET CUR_DIR=%cd%
cd /d "%~dp0.."
SET WAS_HOME=%cd%
cd /d "%CUR_DIR%"
```

This is fine when you run from the command line. You are usually in the ~/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/bin (or other server version) directory. The parent is where you want to be.

I would look into setting the working directory when you run the ws_ant.bat script. That is probably the most likely cause.